# How to read hdmi Input frame buffer using Directx?

Tags: directx, framebuffer, hdmi

I am trying to capture hdmi Input frame buffer using DirectX in windows.  I have been able to find the examples to capture the video frame or stream from a camera using DIRECT X. However I have not been able to find any resource that can help me to read the HDMI IN frame buffer using DIRECT X. Moreover, I know that HDMI content is HDCP protected. It cannot be decoded without a capture card. I have one with me from startech.com but I don't know how to use the video capture card in DIRECT X and capture the frames and process them. Any suggestions to achieve this will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be try [**This**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34663/DirectShow-Examples-for-Using-SampleGrabber-for-Gr?msg=5057536#xx5057536xx) it works nice with `using DirectX.Capture;`: